# Check latest commit with Python in Linux/Windows/Mac

Tags: python, git, operating-system

I'm trying to generate a simple Python code that:

1. checks if it is running inside a `git` folder
2. if so, fetch the latest commit, else skip
3. it should work under the three platforms: Linux, Windows, and Mac

I have this code that works correctly under Linux:

```
from subprocess import call, STDOUT
import os

if call(["git", "branch"], stderr=STDOUT, stdout=open(os.devnull, 'w')) != 0:
    # Not a git folder
    commit = ''
else:
    # Inside a git folder.: fetch latest commit
    commit = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', '{}'.format('HEAD')])

print(commit)
```

but I have no way of checking if itwill work under Windows and Mac.

Does it work? Is there any way of checking/knowing this sort of things when one has no access to the other operating system?

Comment: Have you considered using the Python Git API? https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: I did, but I'm trying to use as many extra packages as possible.

Comment: I mean, you check if a git command runs successfully. Can't you just look for the `.git` folder?

Comment: The first line does that. Unless I'm not understanding correctly your point.

Comment: @SimonFink you need a git command to find the .git folder

Comment: `os.path.exists('.git') and os.path.isdir('.git')`

Comment: @furas that commands will only work if the `.git` folder is in the same folder as the script. If I call the script from another file that **is** in a `git` repo, it will not work.

Comment: so what is the problem to use full path `os.path.exists('/full/path/to/repo/.git')`, etc.

Comment: Also the git command will only work, if you are in the right directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a method check_output in subprocess library

```py
from subprocess import check_output
try:
    # use python to parse this log for info. This is your entire last commit
    logs = check_output(['git', 'log', '-1', '--stat']).decode("UTF-8")
except Exception as e:
    # Do whatever you wanna do otherwise if not git repository
    print(e)
```

Git has a command called "git log".

"-1" indicates the last commit and 
--stat will give you the files that were changed, commit ID, TIME ETC

then you can use python to parse this log and retrive any information you want 
Check this out for more info on [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

Comment: I'm selecting this answer for providing the code and because it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to run `git branch` to detect whether you're in a Git repository, because you may or may not have any branches.  To detect whether you're able to use Git commands, you'll want to run something like `git rev-parse --git-dir`, which will exit non-zero if you're not within a Git repository.

However, there are a couple of other issues with your code.  First of all, in a new repository (one created fresh with `git init`), there will be a `.git` directory and the above command will succeed, but `HEAD` will not point anywhere.  Therefore, your `git rev-parse HEAD` command will fail and print `HEAD` and an error.

Finally, if you want parse a revision, you should usually use `--verify` so that you don't print the dummy `HEAD` value on failure.  So your invocation should look like `git rev-parse --verify HEAD`.

Ultimately, it's up to you to figure out what you want to do in a newly initialized repository, whether that's fail or fall back to an empty string.

The behaviors I've described here are consistent across platforms; they're built into Git and well defined.